# What is Monodroid Application class equivalent in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

In monodroid when you have a attribute that want its value be uniqe in all times when your application is run you can use Application class like this:
namespace RPLAndroidApp
{
    [Application(Label="TestApp",Icon="@drawable/icon")]
    public  class TestApp :Application
    {

```
    private int_tempV;
    public object tempV {
        get;
        set;
    }


public bool OfflineMode{
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override void OnCreate ()
    {
        try {
            base.OnCreate ();
} catch (Exception ex) {
            Common .HandleException (ex);
        }

    }
```

And i use this in my application like this:

```
((TestAPP)Application).tempV
```

Now, the question is this. How can we can use this mechanism in Monotouch for iPhone development?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to achieve, my best guess is: Please search this site for "singleton pattern" - it really seems like this has nothing to do with MonoTouch or Android but is rather C# basics.

Comment: I know what is singleton classes but my question is some thing else. please see my comment on 'user1010710' answer's.

Comment: You can use any static class to hold information for the lifetime of your app. You do not need to use any Android/MT specific classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **UIApplicationDelegate** for this purpose.

But I don't think that this is a good idea. Of course without the knowledge of the problem I can not say for sure, but it maybe you need to create a simple [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class for holding you attributes values?

Comment: In my application I have some attributes that must be unique in all activities. In android application class is a singleton class that is alive until application terminate by OS. therefor we can define this attributes in this class and the used them in other classes. I wanna know that whether iPhone have any class like this or not? if have how can i use this in my other classes?

Comment: Add attributes to your AppDelegate class. You can access it anywhere from your code like that: var appdelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;